# url change with infinite scroll wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, infinite-scroll

Hi if someone could help I would really grateful. I am using the Woohoo wordpress news theme. What I would like to do is when a user clicks to a post that they can just scroll to the next post as well as the url changing when the next posts is scrolled to. I have struggled to find a suitable plugin. The one I found is called smart scroll which does what is supposed to, which is add infinite scroll and it changes the url when in the single post, seen  here (https://wordpress.org/plugins/smart-scroll-posts/). The issues I am having with that is, when I navigate back to the home page all the posts do not display until I refresh the page. Currently I have a standard infinite scroll plugin doing the scrolling but would like to add the url change in as well.

If Someone has come across the issue before and found a fix or even a better way to do this I would be grateful for some help. Thanks

Comment: Will you be able to provide your site's url?

Comment: I would need to add the plugin back as at the minute I have just the normal infinite scroll attached

Comment: Do that if you can and let me know

Comment: Hi thanks for trying to help me Murshid but I managed to figure it out with a little process of elimination! thanks again!

Comment: Ah ok. Glad you figured it out.